# Postgres select value by key from json in a list

Tags: json, postgresql

Given the following:

```
create table test (
  id int, 
  status text
);

insert into test values 
(1,'[]'),
(2,'[{"A":"d","B":"c"}]'),
(3,'[{"A":"g","B":"f"}]');
```

Is it possible to return?

```
id  A     B
1   null  null    
2   d     c
3   g     f
```

I am attempting something like this:

```
select id, 
       status::json ->> 0 @> "A" from test
```

Comment: The `id` numbers in your example are off by one.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yep, thanks. I modified the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to address your specific example :

```
SELECT id, (status :: json)#>>'{0,A}' AS A, (status :: json)#>>'{0,B}' AS B
FROM test
```

see the [result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/770b1/11)

see the [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) :

> jsonb #>> text[] → text
>
> Extracts JSON sub-object at the specified path as text.
>
> '{"a": {"b": ["foo","bar"]}}'::json #>> '{a,b,1}' → bar

Answer (score 0):

This does it:

```
SELECT id,
    (status::json->0)->"A" as A,
    (status::json->0)->"B" as B
FROM test;
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/770b1/12... I think I am getting an error.

Comment: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/770b1/11](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/770b1/11)

Comment: Interesting; that exact query worked for me with Postgres 9.5.